# Splitting text field into 2 separate fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to rework the code below to a new requirement. Essentially what it's doing is taking the Price field and writing the Pounds and Pence to 2 separate fields based on the index of the . symbol,

That is all working great, however I have a new requirement where to take a Name field and write N to a field called name1 and ame to a field called name2. So essentially splitting the name after the first character, however I'm struggling how to rewrite this as not to use the . symbol as the index of trigger, if that makes sense?

```js
$('#price').keyup(function(event) {

  if ($('#price').val().indexOf('.') != -1) {

    $('#pence').val($('#price').val().substr($('#price').val().indexOf('.') + 1, $('#price').val().lengh));

    $('#pounds').val($('#price').val().substr(0, $('#price').val().indexOf('.')));

  } else {
    $('#pounds').val($('#price').val());
  };


});
```

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense, since we don't know what `$('#price').val()` is. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to provide the HTML that goes along with the jQuery (remember to add a reference to jQuery), and that would help make sense of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#fullname').keyup(function(event) {
  // get the value of the main field
  const fullname = $('#fullname').val();
  const
  // set the value for field 1 — get the first character by “[0]” (if there is no fullname fall back to "")
    name1 = fullname[0] || "",
  // set the value for field 2, if fullname is longer than one character get substring from position 1 on else fall back to ""
    name2 = fullname.length > 1 ? fullname.substr(1) : "";
  // set the values of the fields
  $('#name1').val(name1);
  $('#name2').val(name2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label style="display: flex; padding-bottom: 1em;">
  <span>Fullname: </span>
  <input id="fullname" style="display:block; flex-grow: 1;">
</label>
<label style="display: flex; padding-bottom: 1em;">
  <span>Name1: </span>
  <input id="name1" style="display:block; flex-grow: 1;" disabled>
</label>
<label style="display: flex; padding-bottom: 1em;">
  <span>Name2: </span>
  <input id="name2" style="display:block; flex-grow: 1;" disabled>
</label>
```

Description is in the comments.